# Function send old data to server

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a color picker where people can pick a color, so whenever user is going above a color it send the color HEX code to the server.
Now I thought I had a solution but on client-side it works because i use `delete` but everytime I get undefined (which I dont really like).

So i want the function work like this the user can pick a color and on close it must send the most current color to the server after click on close button.
Now it send al picked color codes to the server, how can i avoid this ?

```
    $("#color").farbtastic(function(a) {
        color = a;
        $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").click(function() {
            socket.emit('send color',{type: 'color', value: a}, function(data){
                if(data){
                    if(data.result=='success'){ 
                        console.log(a);
                        delete color;
                    }
                }
            });
        }); 
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback added to Farbtastic is called every time the user chooses a color, and as you're binding an event handler inside that callback, a new click event handler is added every time someone chooses a color, which seems like a bad idea.

Separate the event handlers

```
$("#color").farbtastic(function(a) {
    $("#color").data('fcolor', a);
});

$(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").click(function() {
    var color = $("#color").data('fcolor');

    socket.emit('send color',{type: 'color', value: color}, function(data){
        if(data){
            if(data.result=='success'){ 
                console.log(color);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nmuxwopd/)

Comment: When I do this it doenst trigger the function inside the `click()` function

Comment: And where is the modal coming from, did you open it somewhere

Comment: Yes the dialog poped up, does the code in de fiddle URL work or is it just me ? I didnt get any popup or console

Comment: The fiddle works for me, but again, Farbtastic doesn't create a dialog, where is the modal dialog that you're clicking coming from ?

Comment: The code in fiddle worked for me the click function had some weird reaction. Thank you !